# Excel to calculate summation with exclusion list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I have a table like below:

```
Task Time
a    1
b    2
c    4
d    8
--------
sum  15
```

When a task is finished, I would like to add strike line to the row and exclude it from summation. Adding strike line is easy, just select the row, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>. Is there an easy way to exclude the completed tasks time in summation? So it's easy to tell the remaining time.

Comment: I did not know about `Ctrl 5` to strike through.  Nice tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a third column to mark when an item is completed. Then you can use conditional formatting to handle the strike-through for you, and adjust your sum formulas to automatically account for the completed items. Also, things get a bit easier in the long run if you move your sums to a different column. See the example below.

[image]

Formulas:

- F1 `=SUM(B:B)`
- F2 `=SUMIF(C:C,"Yes",B:B)`
- F3 `=SUMIF(C:C,"No",B:B)`

You're probably already familiar with SUM. The only thing I'm doing here that's different from your example is moving it to a separate column. This way, you can target all of column B with your SUM and not have to adjust the formula every time you add more data.

SUMIF allows you to only sum values that meet a given condition. It requires only two parameters, but for our purposes we also need the third.

- **Range** - This is the range to be tested against the criteria. If the third parameter is omitted, this will also be the range from which values will be summed. In our case, our conditional needs to check the values in column C.
- **Criteria** - This is the criteria that will be checked to determine whether a value gets included in the sum. Text matches, like we've done here, are the simplest but there are also ways to use formulas.
- **Sum Range** - This is an optional parameter. If omitted, then Range is assumed to be the same as Sum Range. This parameter specifies which range of values will be summed. For each cell in Sum Range, SUM will check the corresponding cell in Range against Criteria, and if the check returns TRUE it will add the value from Sum Range into the total. If the check comes up false, that value will be omitted from the total.

So, to translate the formulas:

- F1 `Sum all of the numeric values in column B`
- F2 `Check for cells in column C which have value "Yes", and sum the corresponding numeric values from column B.`
- F3 `Check for cells in column C which have value "No", and sum the corresponding numeric values from column B.`

As I mentioned earlier, the strike-throughs on "Task a" and "Task d" can be accomplished with Conditional Formatting. See the rule below.

[image]

Here, Conditional Formatting has been applied to all of columns A & B using a formula for its criteria. The formula references `$C1` because it represents the relative position of the cell to be checked, starting from A1, for each cell to be formatted. So, for A1, Conditional Formatting looks to see if C1 is "Yes". Since it's not, A1 doesn't get formatted. For B2, Conditional Formatting checks C2. The `$` before the `C` in the formula means that the column for the cell to be checked is *always* C. Since no `$` is put in front of the `1`, the row of the cell to be checked will move according to the row of the cell being formatted (or not formatted, as the case may be).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a cell has been struck through by creating your own formula. This can be achieved by using the Developer tools and creating a module.

> Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
>
> Insert Module
>
> Paste in the following code

```
Function strikethrough(r As Range)
  strikethrough = r.Font.Strikethrough
End Function
```

> Return to the spreadsheet and you can use the formula =strikethrough(A1) to check if the cell has been struck through.

From here it should be possible to accomplish what you're after given that you now know whether a cell has been struck through. I think the formula to achieve this is `=SUMIFS()`